# Failure to make '/tmp/interview-question.xdv'

Tags: latexmk

When I add the latexmk `Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020. Version 4.70b` auxdir parameter, the log output like this and could not trigger open the compiled pdf:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd)
    Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 581--582
    
    
    Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 583--584
    
    [3] [4] (./output/interview-question.toc) [5] [6] [7] [8]
    (./output/interview-question.ptc) [1] [2] [3] [4]
    (./output/interview-question.ind) (./output/interview-question.aux) )
    (see the transcript file for additional information)
    Output written on ./output/interview-question.xdv (12 pages, 23248 bytes).
    Transcript written on ./output/interview-question.log.
    Latexmk: Examining 'output/interview-question.log'
    === TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
    Latexmk: Index file 'output/interview-question.idx' was written
    Latexmk: Log file says output to 'output/interview-question.xdv'
    Failure to make 'tmp/interview-question.xdv'
    Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
    Latexmk: Failure to make the files correctly
        ==> You will need to change a source file before I do another run <==
    Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
      xelatex: failed to create output file
    
    === Watching for updated files. Use ctrl/C to stop ...
```

When I remove the `auxdir` parameter, it works fine. Why did this happen? What should I do to make it work? This is the compile command:

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk -auxdir=./tmp -pdfxe -pvc -xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory="./output" "interview-question.tex"
```

Does latexmk really support `auxdir`? this is the tex version:

```
➜  ~ tex -v
TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2021)
kpathsea version 6.3.3
Copyright 2021 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

Comment: I really would never use these options, they just complicate processing for no benefit, but anyway `auxdir` is a miktex commandline option not supported in texlive. just use output-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`auxdir` relates to a commandline option of miktex implementations of TeX that is not supported in texlive. In texlive just use `output-directory` (Personally I'd recommend never using either option as they increase the complexity of the processing for at best cosmetic benefit)

Comment: if I do not use these option the folder files are to much and too chaos.@David Carlisle

Comment: @Dolphin I have literally thousands of files in folders, using `output-directory`  would move maybe 5 or 6 files so what's the point?, and after telling tex to write the files in a non standard place you need to configure _everything_, makeindex, biber, bibtex, tex, ... to find them. TeX does not write these files for fun, it writes them because other processes need to read them. It is not "chaos" it's the natural processing pipeline to write these structures to a file.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your patients. @David Carlisle

Comment: @David Carlisle  Many of us disagree; we only have modest numbers of files in the folder containing the main .tex file of a document.  Latexmk deals with the complications of using output and aux directories, and then the user doesn't have to deal with them.

Comment: @JohnCollins yes I know I think we have crossed paths on similar questions before:-) But I think a feature that offers no benefits and compilcates things sufficiently that you then require a build system to make it work isn't exactly a good feature even if the build system handles it well, and you should be using a build system for other reasons anyway. We see _loads_ of questions from people confused by `output-directory`. yes I coulds say "use latexmk, it'll sort it out for you" but saying "don't use `output-directory` seems a more direct response (and actually what I do myself)

Comment: @Dolphin can you accept John's answer, then I'll delete this one

Answer (score 1):

Update your TeX Live 2021 so that it has the current version 4.77 of latexmk.

In addition, you should add the `--emulate-aux-dir` option on the command line (or set `$emulate_aux=1;` in a latexmkrc file).  Otherwise, latexmk will first try to use the `-aux-directory` option for the *latex program, then finds it doesn't work with TeX Live, and changes its behavior.  It will also give a message about this at the end of the run. (I'll omit the reasons why latexmk's default behavior is currently as it is.)

Prior to version 4.73, latexmk didn't support the -auxdir option for TeX Live, but only for MiKTeX, with the use of its `-aux-directory` option.

Comment: ah interesting, if the OP moves the tick to you I'll delete mine (as it's wrong, although I think the doc still says it's miktex only?)

Comment: Is `--auxdir` known to TeX Live implementations? I get ``unrecognized option `--auxdir'``

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Ouch.  Parts of the documentation and the on-line help are out-of-date about the MiKTeX-only issue.  I missed seeing that they needed to be changed. I've updated them for the next release.

Comment: @egreg  The `-auxdir` option is for latexmk, not for latex (or pdflatex etc).

Comment: @JohnCollins I'll try not to be so catagorically against these options in future:-)